# Light up Noble gases

Tags: gas-laws, noble-gases

I saw you can light up the Noble gases with a Tesla coil.
Does it also work with a plasma globe?
Are there any other simple ways to make the gases glaw like that?
And does it work with all the Noble gases or only when it is law pressure or something?

P.S. I don't really understand in chemistry, just saw some videos on YouTube.

Comment: Sure it works with a plasma globe, spark discharges, neon bulbs, and so on. It works for all the noble gases and low pressures just facilitate the electrical excitation process. Neon sign transformers do a great job, although they are rather electrically dangerous and not to be taken lightly (sorry for the pun!).

Comment: You can make any gas glow under the right conditions, not just the noble gases.

Answer (score 1):

**Many low pressure gases glow when undergoing an electrical discharge**

Plasma globes are simple vessels containing low pressure gas mixtures (often noble gases). They are usually driven by something like a Tesla Coil (or by an electronic circuit that produces the same high voltage high frequency output as a tesla coil).

Neon signs and standard fluorescent tubes use the same basic principle: an electrical discharge in a low-pressure gas tube emits light. The colour of the light depends on the gases in the tube and their pressure. Most "neon" tubes, fluorescent tubes and plasma globes use fine-tuned gas mixtures at specific low pressures.

So, yes, it is a general phenomenon, but it usually requires low pressure.

Comment: A dinky exception to the low pressure issue is the triboelectric effect observed when sugar crystals (and wintergreen Lifesaver candies) are crushed in air. ;-)